# How to calculate the distance to multiple locations from each cell of my raster?

Tags: raster, arcgis-10.1, distance, attribute-table, nearest-neighbor

I'm working with Arcgis 10.1 and Python 2.7.2

How can I calculate the distance to multiple locations from each cell of my raster?

- I tried euclidean distance but it only provides the distance to the
  **closest** location. I need to know the second closest, third closest and so on until the 150th closest.
- I tried generating a near table but I'm working with high resolution data. The lowest I could go for this dataset are 1,9 million cells. A near table would generare 150 times 1,9 million rows. Looping through these rows takes up a tremendous amount of time.

  Here is an example (scratch of course) of what I'm trying to accomplish.

[image]

*Red dots are locations, grid represents (49) cells, green lines are to show the distance.*

I thought maybe something with an alternated euclidean distance function or an addition of euclidean distances to each single location. I tried combining euclidean rasters, but it didn't work.

Can anyone help me or point me in the right direction? A solution in python would be appreciated but I'm glad for any idea , workaround, anything...

Comment: How many "locations" are involved? Just 150 or are there many more than that?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a Model to solve this

Model Builder - Iterators - Iterate Feature Selection - this will allow you to go through each of your Locations one at a time and create individualized Euclidean Distance grids. Make sure you utilize in-line variable substitution so you are not writing over anything